# facebook small like box vertical, like google plus

Tags: facebook

is there a way to display a facebook like box similar to the google plus one?
Please have a look at www.dadabik.org, right top corner: I would like to have a facebook button similar to the g+ one, with the number of likes. Furthermore, the link should bring the user to the facebook page and not immediately "like" the item.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Cheers,

Eugenio

Answer (score 0):

It will be better if you use  api to get your likes and then designing what you want.
OR 
if you access this URL http://graph.facebook.com/bhavitk.in will give you json data then you can parse it to get your likes

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so there isn't any ready to use likebox like that one? A couple of questions:
1) If I use the graph, where can I get the official icons to build the box as the g+ ones?
2) I didn't get the second part of your answer, after facebook.com/ I am supposed to put the name of the page? With  http://graph.facebook.com/DaDaBIK or  http://graph.facebook.com/DaDaBIK/154757317877584 it doesn't work